# Multi Variable Analysis Book recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently going over Multivariable Real Analysis using the book by Jerry Shurman "Calculus and Analysis on Euclidean Space" and I came across "Advanced Calculus: A geometric View" by James Callahan. Would James's book be great to use alongside a real analysis level textbook or would I be better off searching for other books?
I'm asking since I want to boost my understanding of the subject by utilizing other books. I'm just trying to see what works well with learning this subject.

BTW my current knowledge is: General Topology, Single Variable Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra up to ring theory, Linear Algebra.

Comment: I like Callahan's book. The book by Hubbard and Hubbard may be a little bit cluttered in terms of notation, but contains proofs of all its theorems in the text or in appendices. I never took a multivariate analysis course in undergrad, but I pieced together my knowledge from these books, and Rudin, and turned out pretty okay!

Comment: Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I and II.  The latter is overwhelmingly comprehensive, imo.